# Android Studio: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, anychart

I'm trying to use the AnyChart module for Android Studio, but it keeps giving me the error  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo`.

Here are some notable files:

MainActivity.java

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.anychart.AnyChart;
import com.anychart.AnyChartView;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.ValueDataEntry;
import com.anychart.charts.Pie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
//
//        List<DataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
//        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("John", 10000));
//        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Jake", 12000));
//        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Peter", 18000));

        //AnyChartView anyChartView = (AnyChartView) findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
        //anyChartView.setChart(pie);
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.jack.project"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--    <com.anychart.anychart.AnyChartView-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/any_chart_view"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--        />-->


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the error:

```
    Process: org.jack.project, PID: 956
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.jack.project/org.jack.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.anychart.AnyChartView$JsListener com.anychart.AnyChartView.getJsListener()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.anychart.AnyChartView$JsListener com.anychart.AnyChartView.getJsListener()' on a null object reference
        at com.anychart.APIlib.addJSLine(APIlib.java:27)
        at com.anychart.charts.Pie.<init>(Pie.java:34)
        at com.anychart.AnyChart.pie(AnyChart.java:130)
        at org.jack.project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I've already tried cleaning/clearing cache/restarting/syncing my gradle files.

On the emulator, it says my app keeps restarting.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show the Logcat error.

Comment: @SonTruong I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause**

I went through the [AnyChart-Android](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android) source code and figured out the code flow.

**Step 1.** From our app Activity/Fragment

```
Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
```

**Step 2.** [AnyChart.java](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/anychart/src/main/java/com/anychart/AnyChart.java)

```
public static com.anychart.charts.Pie pie() {
    return new com.anychart.charts.Pie("anychart.pie()");
}
```

**Step 3.** [Pie.java](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/anychart/src/main/java/com/anychart/charts/Pie.java)

```
public Pie(String jsChart) {
    jsBase = "pie" + ++variableIndex;
    APIlib.getInstance().addJSLine(jsBase + " = " + jsChart + ";");
}
```

**Step 4.** [APIlib.java](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/anychart/src/main/java/com/anychart/APIlib.java)

```
public class APIlib {

    private AnyChartView anyChartView;

    private static volatile APIlib instance;

    public static APIlib getInstance() {
        APIlib localInstance = instance;
        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (APIlib.class) {
                localInstance = instance;
                if (localInstance == null) {
                    instance = localInstance = new APIlib();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }

    public void setActiveAnyChartView(AnyChartView anyChartView) {
        this.anyChartView = anyChartView;
    }

    public void addJSLine(String jsLine) {
        anyChartView.getJsListener().onJsLineAdd(jsLine);
    }
}
```

As we can see when we call `addJSLine(String)` method, it call `getJsListener()` method of `anyChartView`, but this instance is only set via `setActiveAnyChartView` method. And this method only called from [AnyChartView.java](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/anychart/src/main/java/com/anychart/AnyChartView.java).

```
@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "AddJavascriptInterface"})
private void init() {
    ...

    APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(this);

    ...
}
```

The `init()` method will be called inside the constructors of `AnyCharView` class.

```
public AnyChartView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public AnyChartView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public AnyChartView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}
```

Because inside `activity_main.xml`, you comment-out the code

```
<!--    <com.anychart.anychart.AnyChartView-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/any_chart_view"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--        />-->
```

That explains why you got the exception.

**Solution:** Make sure there is at least one instance of `AnyChartView` is created.

**Solution 1.** Declare `AnyCharView` inside xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Solution 2.** If you want to add a `AnyChartView` at runtime, then you can use

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val anyChartView = AnyChartView(this)

        val pie: Pie = AnyChart.pie()
    }
}
```

**Note:** I see that this issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/123), but there is no answer yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this for me. The error is gone now, but after uncommenting my code in MainActivity.java (and adding the id of any_chart_view to the element), no pie chart actually shows up. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I followed this link https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/wiki/Getting-started, and I can see the chart is displayed on screen. Can you show your full code and xml file?

Comment: Nevermind, I don't have the problem anymore (your link was a good tutorial). Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that.